# Bootstrap 3 - Remotely loaded modal creates duplicate javascript events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple page with 2 buttons which each populate the content of a modal remotely using the following method code

```
  $("button").click( function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var remoteLoc = $(this).attr('data-loc');
      $("#myModal .modal-content").load(remoteLoc, function() { 
        $("#myModal").modal("show"); 
      });
  });
  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#myModal .modal-content").empty();
  });
```

A simple example of the content being loaded is this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <a id="tomtest" href="#">Test link</a>
  <p>dfghdfgh dfgh dfgh dfgh dfgh dfgh dfgh dfg h</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("click", "a#tomtest", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(123);
  });
</script>
```

The problem is that the alert fires as many times as I've opened the modal since the page loaded.

What can I do to stop this happening?

**EDIT!!!**

Based on the answer from @paulitto I've amended the code to add a dynamically created link in the modal content.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <a id="tomAdder" href="#">Add alert link</a>
  <p>dfghdfgh dfgh dfgh dfgh dfgh dfgh dfgh dfg h</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("a#tomAdder").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<a class="tomtest" href="#">Test link</a>').prependTo(".modal-body");
  });
  $(document).on("click","a.tomtest", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(123);
  });
</script>
```

Any ideas in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using delegated events aproach like `$(document).on("click", "a#tomtest", function(e) {...});` you are binding handlers to elements that do not exist yet, this way you append new handlers to same link each time opening new modal.

Attaching event in usual way whould do it for only existing link:

```
$("a#tomtest").on("click", function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
alert(123);
```

});

Update:

if you still need to use delegated events aproach, you should be able to unbind all delegated click handlers like this, before binding new click handler:

```
$(document).off("click", "a#tomtest" );
```

Comment: I see your point, and that does solve the problem is this case, but what if the link #tomtest is added to the modal dynamically after it is loaded. Then this solution would not work again, right?

Comment: you are right, this won't work if link will be inserted dynamically afterwards

Comment: @Tom: `$("a#tomtest").off("click", "**" );` should unbind all delegated event handlers, give it a try

Comment: right before ` $(document).on("click","a.tomtest", function(){...}`

Comment: Nope... still fires the alert as many times as the modal has been opened.

Comment: are you using same selectors for link? I noticed in original post you used a#tomtest, and then in updated you used class a.tomtest

Comment: I did that because there could in theory be more than one a.tomtest at a time. But anyway, it's still not working... I think that's to do with my implementation of it though. Please stick with it - I think we're getting close!

Comment: you should be able to unbind it this way for sure `$("document").off("click", "a#tomtest" );` updated answer again :)

Comment: Got it! Would you say it's best to unbind in the modal or call the unbind when the modal is hidden? Both work, but not sure which is the best solution.

Comment: As for me, there's no need to put both bind and unbind inside html that you load at all, as you're using delegated events you can keep all js in same place where its more convenient for you, no matter  its hidden or not

Answer (score 1):

Updated to include paulitto's well put point:

Try placing this in your javascript:

```
$(this).off("click");
```

after the alert.  It should then remove it after the first fire.

Comment: its better to use `.off()` instead of `.unbind()` in newer jquery versions