# Bootstrap 3.3.2 Modal events fire multiple times

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Bootstrap Modal Events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events) fire multiple times, or rather always one more time then before. I wrap the modal events in a click function that returns the modal id for now.

How can I make sure the event always only fires once, and only when the click function invoked it?

jQuery

```
$('.img-modal').on('click', function () {

// returns #modal-Id
var modalIdClicked = $(this).attr('data-target')
console.log ('modal id clicked from .img-modal = '+ modalIdClicked);

console.log ('.img-modal clicked');

    $(modalIdClicked).on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

        console.log ( 'show.bs.modal');

    });    

});
```

Default Bootstrap 3.3.2 Modal HTML

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <img class="img-modal img-responsive cursor-pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1" src="www" alt="image">
</div>

<!--  Modal -->
<div class="modal fade top-space-0" id="modal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content cursor-pointer" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="#modal-1">CLOSE &times;</button>
                <h1 class="modal-title">Modal Title</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="img-center">
                    <img class="img-modal img-responsive" src="wwww" alt="image">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--  Modal end -->
```

I did have a look at [jQuery click events firing multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969960/jquery-click-events-firing-multiple-times) and
[Bootstrap 3 - Remotely loaded modal creates duplicate javascript events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966870/bootstrap-3-remotely-loaded-modal-creates-duplicate-javascript-events) and it seems this can be achieved with the `.off` method.

So using `$(modalIdClicked).off().on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {` did the trick in this case.

Can someone please explain to me **why** this `.off` method is needed in this case exactly? I am having **trouble understanding how the click is passed around**.

Does the click reach the Bootstrap JS one more time with every click? Why does it fire the events multiple times without the `.off` method?

Thank you.

(I am trying to learn jQuery from a book, if any one out there really has a **good** book or even **the one and only** book to read about this, then please do shoot me a note, there is so many out there and all claim to be the best naturally.. thank you.)

Comment: In my case, had to put ".off()", because the same modal is loaded from different places. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Why does it fire the events multiple times without the `.off` method?

Because every time the element `.img-modal` is clicked, you are attaching ***a new*** event listener for the `show.bs.modal` event. This is why the event `show.bs.modal` is fired one more time on each click.

> Can someone please explain to me why this `.off` method is needed in this case exactly?

The `.off()` method simply removes the previously attached event(s).

---

You don't need to use the `.off()` method.

Rather than attaching an event listener for the event `show.bs.modal` on each click event, you should just add a single event listener for all elements with class `.modal`:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/a6ak0obn/)

```
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Within the `show.bs.modal` event listener, `this` is bound to the `.modal` element that is shown; therefore you can identify which modal is displayed. In the example above, `this.id` will be `modal-1`.

Comment: Great **explanation** and especially thank you for the **second** part of the answer!! I will have to wrap my mind around a few things in that part. Had the click listener on the `.img-modal` to find the clicked modal, also including traversing the dom with children and so on. This changes a lot if not everything of what I had planned to do with the modal events initially. Thank you, thank you & thank you! Self-taught or by book/school? If by book, **which** one please? A last time, thanks for the solid explanation!!

Comment: @lowtechsun You're welcome--glad it helped. To answer your question, I'm self-taught. Stack Overflow has practically taught me everything I know. I started answering questions without much knowledge/experience; but after 1338 answer, I've learned a few things ;) For core JavaScript, I'd highly recommend ["JavaScript the Good Parts"](http://amzn.com/0596517742) (it's a heavy/in-depth read). The site [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is also excellent.. I haven't read any books on jQuery, I mainly refer to the [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: You explained pretty well and it helped me to resolve my issues.  Learning new stuff from stack overflow everyday.  thx

Answer (score 4):

```
modal.off().on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    modalBody.load(remote_content);
});
```

On my case, I was facing multiple remote_loads. '.off()' helped me unbinding previously bound event to the target modal.

Comment: $('.detail_status').on('change', function () { 'content here' }); was running several times. .off did the trick. Thanks.